# A process (Nginx) run on port 80 but I can't find where the command is

Tags: linux, nginx, mac-osx, unix

I am on Mac OS 10.14.5.

I want to use the port 80 for doing Docker work.

But on my Mac, the port 80 is already used, and surprisingly for me, it's not Apache but Nginx (at least, the page displays Nginx information).

I don't remember to have installed Nginx and in my knowledge, only Apache is installed by default.

The command nginx is unknown (with "whereis" or "which").

I have used a command to see the port used and the process which use them :

`lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P`

The result is :

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
datagrip   273  pom  192u  IPv4 0xd45b6da75f7b84e9      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6942 (LISTEN)
datagrip   273  pom  234u  IPv4 0xd45b6da7615634e9      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:63342 (LISTEN)
datagrip   273  pom  261u  IPv4 0xd45b6da767818e69      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:49863 (LISTEN)
rapportd   310  pom    3u  IPv4 0xd45b6da768e56b69      0t0  TCP *:56546 (LISTEN)
rapportd   310  pom    4u  IPv6 0xd45b6da75afcbb69      0t0  TCP *:56546 (LISTEN)
RescueTim  451  pom   16u  IPv6 0xd45b6da75afcb5a9      0t0  TCP *:16587 (LISTEN)
ssh       6115  pom    5u  IPv6 0xd45b6da768bea8e9      0t0  TCP [::1]:1111 (LISTEN)
ssh       6115  pom    6u  IPv4 0xd45b6da766fcab69      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:1111 (LISTEN)
postgres  7123  pom    5u  IPv6 0xd45b6da757bb2b69      0t0  TCP [::1]:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres  7123  pom    6u  IPv4 0xd45b6da7697ed7e9      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)
```

So, no processes use the 80 port.

When I use locate, I see :

```
@macbook-pro:~$ locate nginx
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.xcsnginx.plist
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/Nginx/conf/nginx.conf
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/Nginx/conf/nginx.conf.default
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/Nginx/sbin/nginx
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcsnginx
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/xcsnginx/xcsnginx.conf
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/nginx.rb
```

Homebrew seems not to be responsible, since `brew list` doesn't display him.

Is it because of XCode? 
Where can I look now?

Answer (score 0):

Try `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/xcs/Nginx/sbin/nginx -s stop`